# Code deletion wars

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, abuse

In the edit queue I stumbled across a code deletion war involving two users, or maybe it is a way to boost their reputations 2 points at a time.  I don't know.

The edits deleted all of the code from a question.

What I can't figure out is, how do edits involving deleting all the code out of a question get approved?

I spent 5 minutes rolling back all of one of the users' edits where they deleted all the code out of questions of another user, and they thereby earned 8 pts.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689894/coolguyyyyy

Should I bother?

Should I flag?

I notice on SO flag applies to questions, answers, and comments, not edits or people.

Thoughts?

Comment: most of the edits are done to http://stackoverflow.com/users/2653444/giri

Comment: Yes, giri also deleted code from the answer of a person responding to one of her questions.  The author of that answer was not coolguyyyy though.

Comment: This is most likely a sockpuppet account. I flagged and hopefully it will be nuked and that "Giri" guy will get suspended. Kudos for noticing!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2762599 Interesting

Comment: If giri approved deleting all of the code from their own question, could they simply be a noob who thought any edit would be helpful?

Comment: @user137487 no. There is also [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18246727/447356) posted by "Giri" where he posted his own answer and accepted it a while ago and today that "Cool guy" posted that exact answer and "Giri" deleted his answer and accepted the new answer. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVko6.png).

Comment: There's clear evidence of sockpuppetry going on here. We're on to it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sounds pretty bizarre.

Comment: @user137487 not bizarre at all, clear case of sock puppet trying to get reputation in illegal ways. :)

Comment: Well, I'm glad I managed to help.  Thanks for clueing me in.

Comment: @ChrisF I see the [main user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2653444/giri) is suspended which is good, but [the sock](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2689894/coolguyyyyy) is still alive, can't it be merged or nuked?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I'll see if there's a need to merge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag one of the posts for moderator attention.

Rule of thumb: when in doubt about suspicious behaviour, flag as other with an explanation, and let the moderators sort it out.

Comment: this "thumb" seems too thick, I'd sharpen it like "when in doubt about suspicious behaviour, _use custom flag explaining the reason for your concern_, and let the moderators sort it out"

Comment: Refined the thumb a little.

Comment: This _appears_ to be a bit of a fundamental misunderstanding on how the system works, we've made sure all involved got the exact help that they needed :)

Comment: @Tim yeah, and the one involved didn't like it and got into an edit rage...